# Control the color of characters' inside separately from their contour (Matlab 'text')

Tags: matlab

When using the `text` function, by changing the colour of the font one only changes the face (inside) colour, for instance

```
text(2,8,'A Simple Plot','Color','red','FontSize',14)
```

Is there a way to also control the colour of the edge (contour) of the letter? I found no information about this in the Matlab (2016) documentation or on forums.

Comment: What do you mean with “only change the face”? Fonts have only one color. There is no separate coloring of the edges. There is a background color though. Could you post a screen shot of what you see? And some code to reproduce it?

Comment: I mean to change the color of the interior separately from the edge. I can't find an image with this effect to show you, although I've seen several, e.g. in research papers. The idea is to make a text that is e.g. yellow on the inside, more readable by having the outer contour black. The code above is just from the matlab documentation

Comment: You make it sound like your text only became red on the inside, staying black on the edges. I suggest you [edit] your question to clarify that.

Comment: There are no edge/face properties of text in Matlab, see here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html and here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/32160-text-border-color-in-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking for the "textborder" function on MATLAB file exchange.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27383-textborder-higher-contrast-text-using-a-1-pixel-thick-border

[image: textborder effect]

We also export the matlab plots to eps or pdf files and refine them in Illustrator or similar apps.